# Uniform continuity of $\arctan x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, proof-verification

> Check if $\arctan x$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$

If I'll show that it's contious on $[0,\pi/2]$ then because it's periodic it would be continuous on $\mathbb R$.

So by the definition and Lagrange's MVT: $|\arctan x-\arctan y|\le|x-y||(\arctan c)'|\le \frac {|x-y|} {c^2+1}$

So because $x,y\in[0,\pi/2]$and  $c\in[x,y]$ we have $\frac {|x-y|} {c^2+1} \le |x-y|\le \delta = \epsilon$

So it's uniformly continuous.

Is that alright ?

Comment: $\arctan$ is not periodic, $\tan$ is. But, you can use the fact that $\arctan$ has finite limits at $\infty$ and $-\infty$.

Comment: @DavidMitra right. Can i change the proof for $x>0$ and $x<0$ ?

Comment: Your approach will work, though. Given $\epsilon>0$, set $\delta=\epsilon$. Then proceed as you did.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what results you are allowed to use, but an easy proof is that

$$\frac{d}{dx}\operatorname{arctan}(x) = \frac{1}{x^2+1}$$

which is bounded (above by 1 and below by 0). From this it follows that $\operatorname{arctan}$ is uniformly continuous since ["any function which is differentiable and has bounded derivative is uniformly continuous"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity#Examples)

Comment: I'm supposed to use the definition of continuity here.

Comment: -1: this doesn't answer the question.